# NSTextField validation and NSSearchField save it's value to recent history on NSButton click

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nstextfield, nsbutton, nssearchfield

I have this setup, my `NSWinow` has two `NSSearchFiled`s with relative autosave search history, one `NSTextField` and a `NSButton`.

`NSSearchFiled` has to autosave the search (wich work right when user press "Enter" key)
`NSTextField` needs to be validated and saved to user prefs (by it's `action`).

The problem is that if i have focus on `NSSearchFiled` and click on `NSButton` the string is not autosaved to recents, if i have focus on `NSTextField` and click on `NSButton` the value is not validated and saved to user prefs...

I've tried this in NSButton action:

```
// SearchF_Name is of NSSearchFiled
[SearchF_Name sendAction:SearchF_Name.action to:SearchF_Name.target];
```

with no luck, and googling doesn't help either... Con you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking the question I've tried the "last option"... and it worked!

this is the code for `- (IBAction)Btn_SearchAction:(id)sender`

```
NSResponder *firstResponder = [[NSApp keyWindow] firstResponder];
if ([firstResponder isKindOfClass:[NSText class]] && [(NSText *)firstResponder delegate] == TextF_ResultLimit) {
    NSLog(@"SearchDelegate::Btn_SearchAction TextF_ResultLimit has focus, let's save it's value");
    [TextF_ResultLimit performClick:self];
}

NSLog(@"SearchDelegate::Btn_SearchAction SearchF_Name saving search value to recent history");
[SearchF_Name performClick:self];
```